# Strain gauges or flex sensors

Tags: sensors

I've been thinking about making myself a fancy data glove. Now that I'm looking into it, I notice a lot of DIY stuff works with these so called flex sensor based on conductive carbon ink.

I'm not familiar with these sensors but from what I have learned so far, they are more expensive and less accurate compared to a simple strain gauge. Or are they just hard to use because of the length and bend radius of the finger?

So actually I'm just wondering what the pros and cons are of these sensors when faced with data gloves.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sensors, which are called flexible or bending sensors, are actually capacitors or coils.  If you bend the structure the value of capacitor or coil going to  be changed. If you can produce the flexible sensor correctly and precisely, you will get good results. However, the sensor used as a strain gauges are includes crystals like piezo and these crystals produces electric vibrations in case of load vibration or bending.

[image]